# Changing the layout & design for a specific set of products

Tags: magento2, product, layout, theme, schedule

On 3 of my products I wanted to change the look & feel along with the layout

As an example, I want to move the product title so I have created a new child theme like below

/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Child_Theme_Name]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="main" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Child_Theme_Name]/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/[Vendor]/[Child_Theme_Name]',
    __DIR__
);
```

/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Child_Theme_Name]/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Child Theme Name</title>
     <parent>[Vendor]/[Parent_Theme_Name]</parent>
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
     </media>
 </theme>
```

In the admin, I have selected that child theme and then cleared all the cache

[image: Design Schedule]

Unfortunately, the product detail page then doesn't change. If I make that change in the parent theme the product detail changes but it naturally affects all products which I don't want.

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a child theme. Just rename your layout file like this: catalog_product_view_id_{id}.xml

Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/product-layouts.html

Or create a layout handle catalog_product_view_special.xml
with your special layout and apply it on your products
using `<update handle="catalog_product_view_special"/>`

HTH, Tom